# Vim macro: increase last number of a line by 1

Tags: vim, macros, gvim

I have a csv file whose last column contains either integers, or the character "-".
I need a vim macro that does the following:

```
If last element of current row is "-":
    Turn "-" to "1"
Else
    Increase the last element of the row by 1
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You have some pseudocode here—what have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: I will be completely honest, not much. I'm currently looking up things but I can't do much with vim other than using it for editing. I know you are supposed to try before asking for help, but in this case I was hoping that the savvies may have a one-liner on the top of their heads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
:%s/[0-9-]\+$/\=submatch(0)=='-'?1:submatch(0)+1/
```

Comment: Thank you. No, this does it for *every* last element. I would like to do that only to the element of the *current* row..

Comment: @geo909 Remove the `%` then.